# Как сформировать запрос в mysql, для вывода месяцев из базы?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, в которой хранятся записи финансовых операций.
Первая запись сделана к примеру в ноябре: 2016-11-10
Последняя запись сделана в апреле: 2017-04-19
Нужно вывести список месяцев где есть финансовые операции таким образом:
Ноябрь, Декабрь, Январь, Февраль, Март, Апрель.
Потом за каждый месяц нужно вывести общую сумму всех платежей.

```
$OplafirstSQL = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM dfort_finance_client WHERE contract = '$id_contract' ORDER BY dfort_finance_client . datesort ASC");

$Oplafirst = mysql_fetch_array ($OplafirstSQL); 

$OplasecondSQL = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM dfort_finance_client WHERE contract = '$id_contract' ORDER BY dfort_finance_client . datesort DESC"); 

$Oplasecond = mysql_fetch_array ($OplasecondSQL); 
echo "Первая оплата: ".$Oplafirst['datesort']."<br>Последняя оплата: ".$Oplasecond['datesort']."<br>";
```

Comment: покажите что у вас получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для MySQL можно использовать ужастик типа

```
SELECT LPAD(MONTH(MIN(`date`)),2,'0'), SUM(`payment`)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)
```

Язык корректируется установкой lc_time_names.

Comment: '$OReqSQL = mysql_query ("SELECT MONTHNAME(MIN(`datesort`)) FROM `dfort_finance_client` GROUP BY MONTH(`datesort`)"); $Req = mysql_fetch_array ($OReqSQL);' и как его вывести

Comment: Да как нужно, так и выводите...

Comment: Получилось так: `$OReqSQL = mysql_query ("SELECT MONTHNAME(MIN(`datesort`)) FROM `dfort_finance_client` WHERE contract = '$id_contract' GROUP BY MONTH(`datesort`) ORDER BY dfort_finance_client . datesort ASC"); while ($Req = mysql_fetch_array ($OReqSQL)){
echo $Req[0]."<br>";
} `  А как сделать вывод месяца числом а не названием по англ.?

Comment: _как сделать вывод месяца числом_ Не поверишь... использовать не MONTHNAME(), а MONTH()...

Comment: Двухразрядное число нужно типо: 01 , 02 , 03, 11 , 12  а выводит оно 1,2,3,4,11,12

Comment: Ну так отформатируйте как нужно. LPAD() в помощь.

Comment: PS. А что Вы будете делать, если данные по платежам имеются больше чем за год? месяцы за разные годы-то объединятся...

Comment: Ничего не понял. Как мне сделать 05, из 5

Comment: _Как мне сделать 05, из 5_ `LPAD('5',2,'0')`

Comment: Не работает функция ваша

Comment: 1) Она не моя, а встроенная MySQL. 2) У меня - работает.

Comment: Как ее написать что бы работала?

Comment: echo LPAD('5',2,'0');

Comment: MySQL не знает, что такое echo. Код в ответе дополнил.

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось!

Comment: Месяца на русском так и не отображаются: `mysql_query("SET lc_time_names = ru_RU");`

Comment: Ну Вы уж не поленитесь посмотреть в документации, как ПРАВИЛЬНО устанавливать значения сессионных переменных...

Comment: @АнтонБатрак Номера месяца вполне достаточно, чтобы при выводе "отформатировать" его как надо. Хоть с ведущим нулём, хоть название полное или короткое в любом падеже, хоть графическим изображением.

Comment: @Sergey Хорошо!